# Parse string separated by commas and line breaks in C

Tags: c, parsing, gcc

I would like to parse a string that contains several line breaks, and each line is divided by commas, I would like to print each element separated by commas from each line. This is what I have tried, but it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char cadena[] = "10,Arbol,3.5\n20,Perro,4.0\n30,Mesa,4.5";
    char cadena_copy[sizeof(cadena)]; // Crea una copia de cadena
    strcpy(cadena_copy, cadena);

    char *linea = strtok(cadena_copy, "\n"); // Tokeniza la cadena por saltos de línea

    // Itera sobre cada línea
    while (linea != NULL) {
        char *token = strtok(linea, ","); // Tokeniza la línea por comas

        // Itera sobre cada valor en la línea
        while (token != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", token); // Imprime el valor
            token = strtok(NULL, ","); // Obtiene el siguiente valor
        }

        linea = strtok(NULL, "\n"); // Obtiene la siguiente línea
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is what I expect the output to be:

```
10
Arbol
3.5
20
Perro
4.0
30
Mesa
4.5
```

But instead I'm getting just the first line:

```
10
Arbol
3.5
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you call `strtok` again with a new non-null parameter, it will forget about the first search you sent it off on, that's why. Consider looking for line feed with another function like `strchr` and then use `strtok` for the commas per line.

Comment: Just as a side note: Prefer using pure English identifiers and write your comments in pure English as well – you *will* be sharing your code with non-hispanophones, and if only here on SO – and for these you make understanding your code pretty hard. Apart from: Don't comment the obvious! I can see pretty well myself e.g. that you are printing values. Comments usually are needed if e.g the reasoning behind is not obvious (other than here).

Comment: Use `strtok_r()` on POSIX systems or `strtok_s()` on Windows to allow your code to work on two strings concurrently.   See the duplicate for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use both in the delimiter string

```
int main() {
    char cadena[] = "10,Arbol,3.5\n20,Perro,4.0\n30,Mesa,4.5";
    char cadena_copy[sizeof(cadena)]; // Crea una copia de cadena
    strcpy(cadena_copy, cadena);

    char *token = strtok(cadena_copy, ",\n");

    // Itera sobre cada valor en la línea
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", token); // Imprime el valor
        token = strtok(NULL, ",\n"); // Obtiene el siguiente valor
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/fMv9evK7W